# Can't upload app to app store because "No matching provisioning file found"

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I just finished developing a Mac app in Swift using Xcode 7. I'm ready to submit it to iTunes Connect/the Mac App Store, so I hit `Archive` (which succeeds), find the build in the list of Archives, then hit `Upload to App Store...`. But Xcode gets stuck on "Loading Signing Assets for [me]." Then an error pops up: **"No matching provisioning profiles for Applications/myapp.app; none of the valid provision profiles allowed the specified entitlements..."**

Here's the error:

[image]

What can I do to solve the error, and get my app on the App Store?

---

A little background:

- My app uses iCloud Key-Value Store, which I have an entitlement properly set up for.
- I've set up Sandboxing for my app (as I've read that's required). I have Sandboxing entitlements set to `Yes` for reading/writing from all file locations & outgoing/incoming network traffic.
- My app is a note-taking app that syncs to iCloud and writes PDFs/txt files to the disk.

The mysterious part of this is that I *do* have entitlements in my app's entitlements file for most of the things mentioned in the warning; here's a snapshot of my entitlements file:

[image]

**So what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue.

It only happened because I was using a beta version of Xcode, then switched to a production Xcode of the previous version. This messed up my entitlements file, which I fixed by removing it, then adding the entitlements back from the `Capabilities` tab, which auto-created a new Entitlements file and submission worked.